# TSQL version 2008-R2 - Recursive Select

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
DECLARE @MAIN TABLE
(
  MainID INT NOT NULL, 
  Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  [Deleted] BIT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @ITEMS TABLE
(
  ItemID INT NOT NULL, 
  ParentItemID INT NULL,
  MainID INT NOT NULL, 
  Data VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO @MAIN (MainID, Name, [Deleted]) VALUES  (1, 'Tool 1', 0)
INSERT INTO @MAIN (MainID, Name, [Deleted]) VALUES  (2, 'Tool 2', 0)

INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (1, NULL, 1, 'Level 1')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (2, NULL, 1, 'Level 2')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (3, NULL, 2, 'Level 1 - Irrelevant')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (4, NULL, 1, 'Level 3')

INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (5, 1, 1, 'Item 1-A')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (6, 4, 1, 'Item 2-C')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (7, 7, 2, 'Item Irrelevant 1')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (8, 10, 1, 'Item 3-E')

INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (9, 1, 1, 'Item 1-B')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (10, 4, 1, 'Item 2-D')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (11, 7, 2, 'Item Irrelevant 2')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (12, 10, 1, 'Item 3-F')

INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (13, 5, 1, 'Item 1-A-1')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (14, 8, 1, 'Item 2-C-1')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (15, 5, 2, 'Item 1-A-2')
INSERT INTO @ITEMS (ItemID, ParentItemID, MainID, Data) VALUES (16, 9, 1, 'Item 1-B-1')


SELECT * FROM @MAIN
SELECT * FROM @ITEMS
```

QUESTION 1:
What's the easiest way to retrieve all record that belong to **ItemID = 1** and ALL it's **recursive** Sub Items and order by ParentHood.

QUESTION 2:
What's the easiest way to retrieve **all records** order by ParentHood.

Thanks a lot ..in advanced !!

Comment: I'm not sure what "order by ParentHood" means. Some sample output of the expected order would be useful. Does this mean by the ParentItemId or something else?

Comment: About halfway down through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx) article you'll find `HierarchyId`.  It's the key to getting the order that I suspect you want.

Comment: Sure, by ParentHood I meant ParendItemID, so all items are ordered by their parents and have the root parents on the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to use a common-table expression which lets you execute a hierarchical query.

```
;With AllItems As
    (
    Select I.ItemId, Null As ParentItemId, M.MainId, M.Name, M.[Deleted]
    From @Items As I
        Join @Main As M
            On M.MainID = I.MainID
    Where ParentItemId Is Null
    Union All
    Select I.ItemId, I.ParentItemId, M.MainId, M.Name, M.[Deleted]
    From @Items As I
        Join AllItems As P
            On P.ItemId = I.ParentItemId
        Join @Main As M
            On M.MainID = I.MainID
    )
Select *
From AllItems
```

[WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30cda/1)

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply and many extra thanks for showing me that there is also Fiddle for SQL :--)

Comment: Looks like it needs an `ORDER BY` clause.